# Can't create graph with dataloader

Tags: amcharts

I'm trying to use the build in dataloader in amchart, problem is that no matter what it will not show a column graph for me.

my fiddle shows the code working but outcommented the problem.

I want to create the graph with dataloader and it returns exacly the same data as when i have typed it in myself... So i'm really stuck here :(

here is the code i'm trying to create the graph with:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
            "type": "serial",
            "theme": "light",
            "marginRight": 70,
            /*
            "dataLoader": {
                "url": "http://taponline.eu/datatablecalls/livedata/dispensesgraph.php",
                "format": "json",
                "headers": [{
                  "key": "x-access-token",
                  "value": "123456789"
                }]
              }
            */
              "dataProvider": [{"pluName":"Classic","dispenses":1485},{"pluName":"Jul","dispenses":1224},{"pluName":"Gordons Gin 2 cl.","dispenses":163},{"pluName":null,"dispenses":0}],
            "valueAxes": [{
              "axisAlpha": 0,
              "position": "left",
              "title": "Dispense Count",

            }],
            "startDuration": 1,
            "graphs": [{
              "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
              "fillColorsField": "color",
              "fillAlphas": 0.9,
              "lineAlpha": 0.2,
              "type": "column",
              "valueField": "dispenses"
            }],
            "chartCursor": {
              "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
              "cursorAlpha": 0,
              "zoomable": false
            },
            "categoryField": "pluName",
            "categoryAxis": {
              "gridPosition": "start",
              "labelRotation": 90
            },
            "export": {
              "enabled": true
            }

          });

http://jsfiddle.net/szmoa8w9/2/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataloader is an external plugin like the export plugin. You need to include the plugin script after your chart includes, i.e.

```
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<!-- dataloader plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js"></script>
<!-- other plugins/themes afterward -->
```

Comment: You are one hell of a champ, how could i miss that :( !! had to remove the dummy header and add this line and it worked like a charm... Always some amazing help in here! THANKS